# How to override "save_model" method ModelAdmin for User model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I try to change logic for saving data in Django admin.
I overriding `save_model` but i get error `"<User: test_user>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.`

```
class UserAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    middle_name = forms.CharField(label='Middle name')

    class Meta:
        labels = {
            'last_name': 'Last name',
            'first_name': 'First name',
            'password': 'Password',
        }

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = UserAdminForm
    fields = ['username', 'password', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'middle_name', 'groups']
    list_display = ['username', 'last_name', 'first_name', ]

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        print(form)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do/implement?

Comment: We need to see what you're actually trying to do in the method. The error suggests that you're trying to update a many-to-many relationship, which you can't do until the primary object has been saved.